# I have trouble in ASP Formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm gonna learn ASP.NET MVC. but why visual studio creating .sln files? it shouldn't be .aspx?!

Comment: These are solution files which are containers for your projects and their files. `aspx` is only one of the types of files in a project/solution.

Answer (score 1):

As defined in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2019):

> A solution is a structure for organizing projects in Visual Studio.

A `solution` can contain any number of `projects`. A project within a solution may be configured to be of type ASP.NET MVC as per your requirement. This project will contain your `.aspx` files.